# Temporary Value Exception

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

Ran into another issue I have not been able to troubleshoot my self for a school assignment.

I get the exception

"System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'ContactId' on entity type 'Contact' has a temporary value while attempting to change the entity's state to 'Deleted'. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.'"

after attempting to delete a contact from a database using a delete button within the page

**Controller**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var contact = context.Contacts.Find(id);
            return View(contact);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Delete(Contact contact)
        {
            context.Contacts.Remove(contact);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

**Delete View**

```
@model Contact
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete Contact";
}

<h2>Confirm Deletion</h2>
<p>Do you really want to delete?</p>

<form asp-action="Delete" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ContactId" />

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-primary">No</a>
</form>
```

**Contact Model**

```
namespace MovieList.Models
{
    public class Contact
    {
        public int ContactId { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }




        public string CategoryId { get; set; }

        public Category Category { get; set; }


    }
}
```

If you think I am missing something, just let me know and I will edit and post up missing code.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to  add value to the  hidden input

```
 <input type="hidden" asp-for="ContactId"  value="@Model.ContactId" />
```

and add validation to delete too

```
[HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Delete(Contact contact)
{
var existingContact = context.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(i=> i.ContactId== contact.ContactId);

if (existingContact==null) return BadRequest("contact is not exist");

context.Contacts.Remove(existingContact);
context.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

and IMHO you need validation for get too

```
 [HttpGet]
public IActionResult Delete(int id)
{
var contact = context.Contacts.Find(id);
if (contact==null) return BadRequest("contact is not exist");
 return View(contact);
 }
```

Comment: I got the exception "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'entity')'" after using that. @Serge. Appreciate the attempt.

Comment: Oh, I will certainly add the validation

Comment: I just updated the code. And it throws the "BadRequest" right away. So its not even finding the id associated with the contact? @Serge

Comment: @MrGovenator Yes, you have a wrong Id , I guess it is just default 0. Post  the view where you submitting id to  get.

Comment: I appreciate the help and additional code. I just solved the issue though. I added a route id set to contactid to the button. @Serge